# Laravel 5.6 .env value resolving as (unknown)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have these values in my .env file:

```
APP_IMG_PATH="/img/"
APP_IMG_LOGO="sclogo.png"
```

Then in my header I do this:

```
<img src="{!! env('APP_IMG_PATH') . env('APP_IMG_LOGO') !!}" class="navbar-logo"/>
```

But the log does not show and in Chrome Inspect I get

```
<img src(unknown) class="navbar-logo">
```

I tried clearing config cache and recreating it:

```
php artisan config:cache;
```

But the result is the same. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After addig new things to env file, you need to clear your cache.

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: This still wouldn't work if config caching is the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Config caching disables env() calls.  Any call to env() will return null once the config is cached.

Perhaps a poor choice by the Laravel team, but the idea is to encourage you to use config(), not env() within your code.

Instead, add new lines to your config/app.php (if that's where you choose):

```
'img_path' => env('APP_IMG_PATH'),
'img_logo' => env('APP_IMG_LOGO'),
```

Then re-create your config cache and use `config('app.img_path')` and `config('app.img_logo')` within your application.

Comment: Indeed! As Laravel docs says:
If you are using the config:cache command during deployment, you must make sure that you are only calling the env function from within your configuration files, and not from anywhere else in your application.

If you are calling env from within your application, it is strongly recommended you add proper configuration values to your configuration files and call env from that location instead, allowing you to convert your env calls to config calls.